# Lucene performance drop with single character

Tags: performance, full-text-search, lucene

I am currently using Lucene to search a large amount of documents.

Most commonly it is being searched on the name of the object in the document.

I am using the standardAnalyser with a null list of stop words. This means words like 'and' will be searchable.

The search term looks like this (+keys:bunker +keys:s*)(keys:0x000bunkers*)

the 0x000 is a prefix to make sure that it comes higher up the list of results.

the 'keys' field also contains other information like postcode.

So must match at least one of those.

Now with the background done on with the main problem.

For some reason when I search a term with a single character. Whether it is just 's' or bunker 's' it takes around 1.7 seconds compared to say 'bunk' which will take less than 0.5 seconds.

I have sorting, I have tried it with and without that no difference. I have tried it with and without the prefix.

Just wondering if anyone else has come across anything like this, or will have any inkling of why it would do this.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you know that it is Lucene that is performing slower? It may be the code performing the search that is slowing based upon the result set. How are you testing the searches?

Answer (score 1):

The most commonly used terms in your index will be the slowest terms to search on.

You're using StandardAnalyzer which does not remove any stop words. Further, it splits words on punctuation, so `John's` is indexed as two terms `John` and `s`. These splits are likely creating a lot of occurrences of `s` in your index.

The more occurrences of a term in your index, the more work Lucene has to do at search-time. A term like `bunk` likely occurs much less in your index by orders of magnitude, thus it requires a lot less work to process at search-time.